# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code

```
$eid = rand(10000, 99999);

$this->db->select('eid');
$this->db->from('student');
$data['eid'] = $this->db->get();

foreach ($data['eid'] as $d) {
    if ($eid == $d) {
        $eid + 1;
    } else {
        $eid = $eid;
    }
}
```

I want to check unique eid for each student, but it gives

> Object of class mysqli could not be converted to int'

The error on this line `foreach ($data['eid'] as $d )`

Comment: could you  do `var_dump($data['eid']);` and post that.

Comment: where to add var_dump

Comment: $d is an object and you are trying compare it with integer. this is the problem.

Comment: above `foreach`.

Comment: var_dump is not working

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
$data['eid'] = $this->db->get();  // It return an Std Class Object
```

and then:

```
if ($eid == $d) {
```

here you are comparing an `object` with a number `$eid`

Comment: Yes, try this .

Comment: it gives error 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: Try this $eid ==$d['eid']

Comment: again error 'Cannot use object of type mysqli as array'

Comment: what is `$eid`  here ?

Comment: its  enrollment id  and rand number saved in database

Comment: m inserting unique rand number for each record as eid...i just checking if there any same number exist in databse or not

Comment: if it exists m addind eid by one ..if it not exists m saving as it is

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can do this like

```
foreach ($data['eid'] as $d) {
if ($eid == $d->eid) {
    $eid + 1;
} else {
    $eid = $eid;
}
}
```

Just replace

```
if ($eid == $d)
```

with

```
 if ($eid == $d->eid)
```

It will work fine.

Comment: i hv tried this it gives 'Trying to get property of non-object'